# Integral sign is too small

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

When using math mode the integral sign appears always like in inline math mode and does not stretch to the proper size, like this

[image: integrals]

and even adding `\displaystyle` before the integral does nothing. I am using this code

```
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
%
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{amsmath,empheq}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Lining,Monospaced}}
\setsansfont{Corbel}
\setmonofont{Consolas}
\setmathfont[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{Cambria Math}

\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\int \diff u \frac{\sqrt{u}}{u}
\end{equation*}
or
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{\frac{2\mathcal{P}}{m}(t-t_0)+v_0^2} \diff u \frac{\sqrt{u}}{u}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that's what I got when I compiled your code (with XeLaTeX). The integral sign looked fine.

[image: XeLaTeX]

Looking late at your question tags, I recompiled (with LuaLaTeX). Still the integral looks fine.

[image: LuaLaTeX]

Comment: So is it a problem with my machine? I am using lualatex with windows 10. How can I see the version of texlive I am using?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX) 
 restricted system commands enabled. Is it due to the fact I am running an old version of TexLive?

Comment: I am not sure but may be Miktex distribution works better with windows. Update if you have the privilege!

Comment: I updated the distribution and this solved the problem. Thank you